# Prometheus cAdvisor reports multiple entries for the same container

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, cadvisor

From cadvisor's metrics within Prometheus, I noticed that multiple entries refer to the same container with slightly different naming conventions

```
/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-<container>
k8s_<pod_name>_<container>
k8s_POD_<container>-<pod_uid>
```

The corresponding metric values are quite different between these entries. If I want to query information (e.g. CPU or Memory usage) of a container, how would I have to define the relationship between all those three (e.g. an aggregation for Memory). Or is one entry which is sufficient to represent the container?

Comment: Which versions of prometheus and cadvisor are used?

Comment: @moonkotte I am using the latest stable version for cAdvisor (v0.37.5) and 2.0.0 for prometheus

Comment: How exactly did you install `prometheus`? Using `helm` (which version then) or `manifest`? I need these details to reproduce the closest possible environment you have. Also is it managed kubernetes (like AWS EKS or GCP GKE) or cluster set up with `kubeadm`?

Comment: @moonkotte A manifest where I used this image quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.0.0. The cluster is set up with kubeadm. I also deployed cadvisor on each node using a Daemonset and scrape the metrics from these (instead of using the metrics from kubelet). Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for response. Are you sure it's `v2.0.0`? This was released in `November, 2017` and very old. Also please provide a manifest or installation steps so we have [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there are way to many small things which can change the final result.